# Getting last elements in list while uing json array

Tags: json, list, jsp

while passing list to json object i am not able to read all the elemnts.. it shows only the list which i stored very last

```
 List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();   
 for (int i=0 ; i<columnCount ; i++)
 {
     while (rs.next())
     {
         list.add(rs.getString(rsMetaData.getColumnName(i+1)));
     }
     json.put(rsMetaData.getColumnName(i+1), list);

     //json.accumulate(rsMetaData.getColumnName(i+1), list);
 }
```

Comment: What is the variable rs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the answer ...this is my code

try
{                   HashMap map= new HashMap();
                    List list = new ArrayList();

```
                int col = 0;
                while (rs.next())
                 {
                    values = new JSONObject(); 
                    for (int i=0 ; i<columnCount ; i++)
                     {
                         values.put(rsMetaData.getColumnName(i+1),rs.getString(rsMetaData.getColumnName(i+1)));
                     }      
                     list.add(col, values.toString());
                     System.out.println(list.toString());
                     col++;
                 }
                json.put("gaea", list);



            }//try block end
```

Answer (score 0):

1. ResultSet is a iterator who is iterated only once, for the first column.
2. The List-Object is only created once and strored multiple to json. Even if you store the list for the first column, you change this first-column value in the second column.

Try this:

```
while (rs.next()) {
    for (int i=0; i < columnCount; i++) {
        String columnName = rsMetaData.getColumnName(i+1);
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (json.get(columnName) == null) {
            json.put(columnName, list);
        } else {
            list = (List<String>)json.get(columnName);
        }
        list.add(rs.getString(columnName));

    }
}
```

BTW: Duplicate columnNames are not supported by json